# Trouble using Laravel Eloquent here

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I'm facing a little trouble returning an array using the Eloquent way in Laravel.
I have two tables:

1. menu_items 
   This table stores name of the menu items and its id.
2. residents 
   This table stores resident's (customer) name and id's of their menu selections for lunch and dinner.

Fiddle [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353e61/5).

I want to do something like:

```
$resident = Resident::first();

return $resident->lunch_meal;
// Roast Beef

return $resident->lunch_desert;
// Ice Cream

return $resident->dinner_meal;
// Chicken Pasta
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where's your code/models/relations?

Comment: Hi kerbholz, please refer to the fiddle link to see my tables, and I didn't mention any model or relation because the question is related to basic Laravel method not any model. I just tried to explain the situation by giving an example in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$resident = Resident::first();

//return $resident->lunch_meal;
// Roast Beef
return MenuItems::where('id',$resident->lunch_meal)->first()->name??'default';
```

Comment: Hi Evol, I may need to return the item names for all of the menu items resident have chose (eg: Lunch, Dinner, both Deserts and Soup). So that means, I have to run your provided code each time for all individual items???